# How to disable all GUI elements and boot to command prompt

Tags: 10.04, gdm, gui, headless

Cross post from [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/278292/ubuntu-10-04-desktop-how-to-disable-all-gui-elements-and-boot-to-command-prompt)

I have a laptop I'm running as a file server, which is running Ubuntu 10.04 Desktop. Now that summer heat is here, and because I love the environment, I'm look for all sorts of ways to reduce the laptop's power/memory/heat footprint.

One part I never touch any more is the GUI as the lids always closed.

I thought perhaps simply removing GDM from all run-levels my achieve this, so I did so using sysv-rc-conf. However this didn't make any difference and upon reboot the lovely Ubuntu boot screen and graphical login prompt appeared.

Please help!

<del>Additionally, perhaps this is a silly question, I want to make sure that the monitor is off at all times the lid is closed, which it is already set to do when the GUI is running, can/do I need to configure this separately for non-GUI environments?</del> (Seems to be doing this fine)

Thanks :D

**EDIT**: Ok maybe I'm using sysv-rc-conf wrong and it needed 2 reboots to apply the settings or something? As rebooting it a second time since removing GDM from all run levels I got a command prompt.

However I didn't watch it reboot and was a little confused by this, so I rebooted what I believe to be a 3rd time, and now it's booted to a black screen with a solitary white underline in the top-left, no other text. No amount of keyboard mashing in order to change run levels is having any effect, however I am able to access it via SSH and the SMB shares, so I suppose it's doing almost what I want. The lack of a CLI on the screen itself is still concerning however.

Comment: for your reference: [Cross-Posting questions that are on-topic on multiple Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1480/cross-posting-questions-that-are-on-topic-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: No problemo! I'll try to be more patient in future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-purpose using **tasksel**

Install `sudo apt-get install tasksel`

run `sudo tasksel`

Uncheck `ubuntu-desktop`

Check `basic server`

Comment: Just went through this, seems to have worked, but now networking seems to have been deactivated among god knows what else. You made it look too easy!

Comment: OK, seems all I needed to do was configure interfaces, pretty much all my other services survived.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, currently, the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel) says you should only use tasksel to install tasks, never to remove any (see [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tasksel/+bug/574287) details)