# Purge GUI from Ubuntu

Tags: headless

I have a pivot box that I access only through SSH.  It has a small hard disk and I will never use GUI apps on it so I want to purge those.

Ubuntu 16.04.  Please recommend a safe way to do this.

EDIT:  Some people think that this is a duplicate of [How to disable all GUI elements and boot to command prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47647/how-to-disable-all-gui-elements-and-boot-to-command-prompt/47650#47650).  Reading them both makes it clear that it is not.  That one is about Ubuntu 10.04, not 16.04.  And the answer there doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04 but anyway why would it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable all GUI elements and boot to command prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47647/how-to-disable-all-gui-elements-and-boot-to-command-prompt) and [How do I turn a laptop into headless Ubuntu server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1017244/)

Comment: No I don't see any similarity between those and my question.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix That command just deleted the `ubuntu-desktop` package and nothing else was autoremoved as a result.

Comment: As I understand it, you're asking how to *remove* the GUI and graphical applications, while retaining the software typically useful in a headless server. [That answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/47650/22949) says how to do that. If that doesn't do what you want, doesn't work, or you know it's not what you're looking for, then I recommend you **[edit]** your question with details about that. Your edit will get the question reviewed for possible reopening.